# VS code intellisense with es6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is there a way to make VS Code intellisense work when a module method is instantiated this way :

**lib.js :**

```
export function foo() {
    this.aMethod = function() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
```

**main.js :**

```
import { foo } from "./lib.js";

function bar() {
    this.newFoo = new foo();
    this.newFoo.  <-- no intellisense here, "aMethod" is not suggested...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Why don't you use a `class` instead? If you want to stick with a function, use `this.aMethod` instead of `var aMethod`.

Comment: You're right, I wrote it wrong and my example was not pertinent. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of defining your class is either by doing

```
export function foo() {
    this.aMethod = function() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
```

or

```
export function foo() {
}

foo.prototype.aMethod = function() {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

VSCode should be able to detect your object's method after that

Comment: Yes, my first example was wrong, I edited it to show the real problem.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea about the corrected version of the issue ?

Comment: screenshot taken from 1.17.2. You might also want to check the file extension. Is it .js or an extension associated with JavaScript ?

Comment: It's .js. My version is 1.18.1 But your screenshot is about the first version of my question, which was wrong. Did you tried the edited version ? Thks.